# git - can't clone (using SSH) from personal remote repository

Tags: github, ssh, git-clone

on my terminal I do :

```
git clone git@github.{myGithubUsername}/{my-repo-name}
```

in order to clone a repo I've created on my personal GitHub account.

I've opted to clone using SSH.

I get :

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I understand there's smth wrong with the SSH authentication but at no point am I asked to validate anything SSH related.

**NOTE:** I already have an SSH key on my machine, which I've copied on GitHub and I'm using in order to work on repos of another user.

I thought I might need to create a new separate SSH key in order to work on my own personal repo but when i try to create a new SSH key on machine it says it will have to overwrite the existing one. So I'm guessing (?) I can use the existing SSH key for multuple repos (my own ones and those of others).

Still I don't know how to *link* this personal repo of mine with that existing SSH key in order to be able to clone it.

Comment: Does normal cloning over HTPPS work? Is 2FA turned on?

Comment: Make sure that contents of `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` in your machine and ssh key in your github profile are same.

Comment: 1. the contets of the file are the same because I'm already using this key with a repo of another user and it's working fine, 2. cloning over HTTPS does not work either 3. yes,  I have 2FA turned on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `.com:` part.

The right syntax is: `git clone git@github.com:{myGithubUsername}/{my-repo-name}`

If it still doesn't work, consider executing this first:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/{you_key_name_here}
eval `ssh-agent`
```

Comment: Yes I forgot to add it in the original post, I'm using the correct syntax in the terminal though. What is `{your_key_name_here }` ?

Comment: Look in the directory `~/.ssh` to find the name of your ssh key (it usually looks like `id_rsa`)